# REST GET method on SharePoint list

Tags: json, rest, sharepoint, api-design

Morning all

I'm new to REST, what I'm trying to do is to prove that I can get an get a sorted column (Exchange_x0020) in a SharePoint list, but I'm not sure if I'm putting the right information in the right format for the API, I'm getting a lot of squiggly reds in Visual Studio Code! Here's the code:

```
function getListItemById(/sites/it/Tools/IT-Contracts/Lists/IT%  
20Contracts/AllItems.aspx, Currency Exchange Rates, Exchange_x0020,  
success, failure) { 
  var url = webUrl + "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/" + "Currency Exchange Rate + "(" +Exchange_x0020 + ")"; 
  $.ajax({ 
      url: url, 
      method: "GET", 
      headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }, 
      success: function (data) { 
          success(data.d); 
      }, 
      error: function (data) { 
         failure(data.responseJSON.error); 
     } 
  }); 
 } 




  //Usage 

 getListItemById(/sites/it/Tools/IT-Contracts/Lists/CurrencyExchangeRates/AllItems.aspx,'Tasks',2,function(taskItem){ 
 console.log(taskItem.TaskName);  
}, 
function(error){ 
  console.log(JSON.stringify(error)); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**General JavaScript Syntax Problems**

In your function definition, you'll need to be more careful with your parameter names.

What you have now:

```
function getListItemById(/sites/it/Tools/IT-Contracts/Lists/IT%20Contracts/AllItems.aspx, 
    Currency Exchange Rates, Exchange_x0020, success, failure)
```

Each parameter should be valid for naming a variable. Slashes, spaces, minus signs, and percent symbols are not valid in variable names.

What makes more sense:

```
function getListItemById(webUrl, listName, columnName, success, failure)
```

The first line of the function would then need to be updated to employ the new parameter names:

```
var url = webUrl + "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/" + listName + "(" + columnName + ")";
```

You should also be careful about quotation marks around your variable names within the body of your function. There should not be a preceding quotation mark for your `listName` variable (your code currently says `+ "Currency Exchange Rate +`).

**Using the SharePoint REST Web Service**

To retrieve items from a list and sort by a specific column, use the `$orderby` parameter.

```
"/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/CurrencyExchangeRates?$orderby=ExchangeRate"
```

Note that the 2010 REST web service uses the list title and column display names with spaces removed, as in the above example. The 2013 REST web service lets you use the actual list title or the list's GUID.

```
"/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items?$orderby=ExchangeRate"
```

See the [SharePoint 2010 REST Interface MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Thanks! Right! So excuse my stupidity but in the function getListItem I don't actually need to put the URL, listName etc? Below what I've got now, it's not returning  success or failure in the Console but I think I'm closer...

Comment: function getListItemById(webUrl, listName, itemID, success, failure) { 
     var url = webUrl +"/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/CurrencyExchangeRates?$orderby=ExchangeRate"(" +Exchange_x0020 + ")"; 
     $.ajax({ 
         url: url, //+ "/sites/it/Tools/IT-Contracts/Lists/IT%20Contracts/AllItems.aspx('+ Currency Exchange Rates +')/items(" + Exchange_x0020 + "), 
         method: "GET", 
         headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },

Comment: @Dazza A good way to test whether your URL is built correctly is to try navigating to it directly in your browser. If the URL is valid, Internet Explorer will display it as a feed. If invalid, you'll get 400 Bad Request (page not found).  `[website url]/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/ListTitle?$orderby=ColumnDisplayName` Replace `ListTitle` with the title of your list (with spaces removed) and replace `ColumnDisplayName` with the display name of your column (with spaces removed). You shouldn't need any parentheses in the URL.